# pycharm: how to type a single quote?

Tags: pycharm

How can I type a single quote, without pycharm automatically inserting a closing quote? For example, typing `'` in front of `{}`:

```
'''say {}'''.format('a')
```

results in

```
'''say ''{}'''.format('a')
```

whereas what I want is

```
'''say '{}'''.format('a')
```

The intent is to enclose `{}` in single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable it like so:

[image]

Disable the pair quote and you will not have this problem.